# Java NumberFormat seams to be stuck on / permanently overriden to english format

Tags: java, locale

I am trying to parse a german number from a string. Here is a minimal example:

```java
String stringValue = "1,00";
double value = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(stringValue).doubleValue();
// value = 100.0 (locale machine from cmd, server jdk)
// value = 1.0 (locale machine from cmd, locale jdk)
```

Somehow the format is permanently stuck at an englisch formater. I debugged the line and had a look at the `symbols.decimalSeperator` and it is still a dot.

I must admit, that I can only reproduce this behaviour if I run the application with a JDK from a server in our company. Running it with my locale JDK everything works fine and as expected. So maybe the locale `Locale` on the server is englisch, but how can this override my hardcode `Locale.GERMANY`?

We are using Java 8.

Comment: What do you expect to have? I run your code and the output is `1.0`.

Comment: Seam here running the code on my locale machine with my local jdk, but running it from cmd with the jdk located on a server in our company, I get `100.0` instead of `1.0`

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in JDK, do your both JDKs have the same version and update number, for instance 8u251? There is a partially reported bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8227830, I would recommend to check the update number of your jdk (maybe helps)

Comment: I can reproduce this for JDK 8u241 and 8u231 on the server, on my machine I have 8u231 and it is working, but I will give that a try and check the bug. I read in the comment, that the bug you mentioned is really old, so that might be the problem.